# get src on selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using "Image Picker" plugin and I want to get all "data-image-src" of all selected options. Here's my code:

```
<select class="image-picker show-labels show-html" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="9122" data-image-src="www.first.com/first.jpg">
      First
  </option>
  .
  .
  .
</select>
```

I can get all values selected by using  `$(".image-picker").val();`. How can I get the "data-image-src"? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can

1) Target the selected option elements.

2) Then use jquery `.map()` to return the `data-image-src`.

3) Use `.get()` to get them in array:

```
$(".image-picker :selected").map(function(){
     return $(this).attr('data-image-src');
}).get();
```

Comment: I tried copy+paste this in console, it just didn't work.

Comment: can you share the link??

Answer (score 1):

Use `option:selected` to get all selected values and `.data()` is to get image src of the selected option

```
$(".image-picker").find("option:selected").map(function(){
     return $(this).data('image-src');
}).get();
```